Grassmann Numbers, anticommutation and derivative rules
If $\psi(t)$ is a complex Grassmann number and $\psi^*(t)$ is its complex conjugated. The following is true:
$$\frac{\partial (\psi^*\psi)}{\partial \psi}=-\psi^*\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \psi}=-\psi^*.\tag1$$
If now consider their derivatives w.r.t time $\dot{\psi}^*(t)$ and $\dot{\psi}(t)$ and I want to check the above derivation for their derivatives, should there be an anticommutation present?
If I have:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \psi} (\dot{\psi}^*\psi).\tag2$$
Would the fact that the complex conjugated value  is the derivative w.r.t to some other quantity e.g time play a role in the derivation? Or would I get $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \psi} (\dot{\psi}^*\psi)=-\dot{\psi}^*.\tag3$$
Additionally if I know consider the derivative w.r.t to ${\psi}^*$ or $\dot{\psi}^*$ would the rules change?
$$\frac{\partial (\psi^*\psi)}{\partial \psi^*}=-\frac{\partial \psi^*}{\partial \psi^*} \psi=-\psi.\tag4$$


For what it's worth, OP is apparently considering left derivatives, which means that the derivatives act from left, and that it satisfies the following graded Leibniz rule
$$ \frac{\partial_L}{\partial z}(fg)~=~ (\frac{\partial_L}{\partial z}f)g+(-1)^{|z||f|}f(\frac{\partial_L}{\partial z}g).$$
Here $|\cdot|$ denotes Grassmann-parity.

In OP's examples
$$|\psi|~=~|\psi^{\ast}|~=~|\dot{\psi}|~=~1\mod 2.$$


